# Upgrading from Grails 2.0.3 to 2.2.1: Server access Error: Connection refused

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock, geb

I'm trying to upgrade from Grails 2.0.3 to 2.2.1 as part of my Happy Trails application.

https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/tree/grails2

The first thing I struggled with was getting Geb/Spock to work with Groovy 2. I was getting the following error when trying to install plugins or do just about anything.

```
| Resolving plugin JAR dependencies
| Error WARNING: Dependencies cannot be resolved for plugin [mail] due to error: startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/Users/mraible/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-1.8.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.7.0-groovy-1.8 is not compatible with Groovy 2.0.7. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
```

I was able to workaround this using the [spock instructions for Grails 2.2](http://grails.org/plugin/spock).

However, now I'm stuck with a strange error where Grails seems to be trying to download articles from a local repository.

```
$ grails compile
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/codehaus/geb/geb-spock/0.9.0-RC-1/geb-spock-0.9.0-RC-1.pom
    Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-releases-local/org/codehaus/geb/geb-spock/0.9.0-RC-1/geb-spock-0.9.0-RC-1.jar
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.9.0-RC-1
```

Here's the diff for my project so far:

https://gist.github.com/mraible/5161209

Comment: Check the [geb grails example pull request](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/pull/7/files). This upgrades the example to 2.2.

Comment: Can you run the `dependency-report` command? If so, look for 'geb-spock' in the dependencies. Grails is looking for it in the wrong package (org.codehaus.geb is the old one), which suggests some stale dependency cache information.

Comment: Try adding 'legacyResolve true' to the grails.project.dependency.resolution closure. Just to make sure it isn't something with the new resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have looked at the source code for the project, I'm going to offer up another suggestion: remove all the plugin entries from `application.properties` and add the ones you need to `BuildConfig.groovy`.

I think the big problem here is that geb 0.7.0 is declared in `application.properties` while 0.9.0-RC-1 is in `BuildConfig.groovy`. You don't need the `svn` plugin entry, so don't add that to `BuildConfig.groovy`. And you will have to upgrade Searchable plugin to 0.6.4.

Comment: The server access error: connection refused seems to be caused by the rateable plugin. I suspected this when I saw localhost in its custom repositories. http://grails.org/plugins/rateable This worked in 2.0.3. Anyway to suppress this error in 2.2?

Comment: Turned out to be caused by having geb-spock in BuildConfig.groovy twice. Once with the old package name, once with the new. Removing the old one got me past the issue.

Comment: Changing the following line to `inherits false` should solve the repository issue: https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/blob/grails2/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L19

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce for love nor money, but I'll hazard a guess that you have stale dependency information in the Ivy cache. Try moving `~/.grails/ivy-cache` to `/var/tmp` and running `grails compile`. If that works, you can leave things as they are, or restore the old cache and just delete the geb related directories:

- ~/.grails/ivy-cache/org.codehaus.geb
- ~/.grails/ivy-cache/org.gebish
- ~/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.plugins/geb

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting (renaming) ~/.grails/2.2.1